# Parsing remote web with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64983/468251 - Hello, I have question about this code, how made that working with remote website url, and how got value = fooId['value'] from all inputs, no only from first?

Comment: You can post your request for information on that answer.  Don't post a new question here.  Add a comment to the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example use a local file. If you want to use a remote site, you need to download the file from the server and parse the html.

You can look at [request](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) for this.

I hope it helps

Comment: import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('http://...').read()

work, but how take elements from soup.findAll (there is example with soup.find)?:)

Comment: from doc: The find method is almost exactly like findAll, except that instead of finding all the matching objects, it only finds the first one.

Answer (score 2):

When you parse url on the internet, you need to find a way to download the page content html first. There are great libraries, like requests, which is said to be best for python. Say you want to parse https://stackoverflow.com/

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
page_html = response.text
```

The page_html is the page html in python string, then you can treat it like a local html file, and preform any kind of parsing on them.

As for getting all the occurrence of a pattern, you can do `soup.findAll('input',name='fooId',type='hidden')`, instead of just `soup.find()`. The soup.findAll will return a list of all occurrence.